# Pipeline fails with name error on Dataflow runner but not on Direct runner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have created a Python based pipeline that contains a `ParDo` that leverages the Python base64 package.  When I run the pipeline locally with DirectRunner, all is well.  When I run the same pipeline with Dataflow on Google Cloud, it fails weith an error of:

```
NameError: name 'base64' is not defined [while running 'ParDo(WriteToSeparateFiles)-ptransform-47']
```

It seems to be missing the `base64` package but I believe that to be part of standard python and always present.

Here is my complete pipeline code:

```
import base64 as base64
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.io.fileio as fileio
import apache_beam.io.filesystems as filesystems
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class WriteToSeparateFiles(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, outdir):
        self.outdir = outdir
    def process(self, element):
        writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create(self.outdir + str(element) + '.txt')
        message = "This is the content of my file"
        message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
        base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)  ### Error here
        writer.write(base64_bytes)
        writer.close()

argv=None
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    outputs = (
        pipeline
        | beam.Create(range(10)) # Change range here to be millions if needed
        | beam.ParDo(WriteToSeparateFiles('gs://kolban-edi/'))
    )
    outputs | beam.Map(print)
    #print(outputs)
```

#### Solution

The solution has been found and is documented here

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much study, a section in the Google Dataflow Frequently Asked Questions was found titled: "[How do I handle NameErrors?](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors)"

Reading that documentation, the suggestion was to add an extra runner parameter called `--save_main_session`.  As soon as I added that to the execution, the problem was resolved.